# New to github: need guidance

Tags: git, github, patch

I am very new to GitHub and need some guidance on how to get things done.

I am working on the project that is hosted on the GitHub. So what I did is I cloned the repository and started working. I didn't make any branches: local or remote.

When I finished I just created a patch using "git diff" command and sent it to the maintainer. But he replied that he couldn't apply it and asked me to do it.

Can someone point me to the link or reference a post here on stackoverflow that explains how to apply a patch properly? If I made a mistaked by not making a branch I can easily redo the cloning as I already have a patch file and can just apply it manually next time around.

Thank you.

Comment: What is your operating system? Did you read the nice documentation on http://github.com/ and on http://git-scm.com/documentation ???? What exact commands did you type?

Comment: The mantainer is the github repo owner? Well seems like what he wants you to do is fork his repo (easy to find button on the GitHub page of HIS project), then clone YOUR forked version of his project, make the changes, push your changes to your forked repo of his repo and than do a Pull Request...

Answer (score 3):

The procedure that is customary for contributions to a project on GitHub is described in the [Fork a Repo](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo) tutorial.

What you should ask the mantainer, given that you are already in touch, is if you should create a new branch for your contributions, or use some of his already created ones, or just use the master branch.

After you follow that tutorial, you can "merge" the commits you already made to that repository, you don't need to generate a diff, just incorporate the commits.

So, after following that tutorial, having cloned your own version of his project to a local working copy, you can merge your changes:

Considering his cloned repository is checked out at mantainer_repo (and that you have commited your changes to his repository in that location) and your forked is checked out at your_repo:

```
cd your_repo
git pull ../maintainer_repo
```

This should merge the changes you made on his repo into yours, then:

```
git push origin
```

Will get that merged changes back into your repository on GitHub. Then you should follow the [Pull Request Tutorial](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests).

Answer (score -2):

You are confusing `git diff` with `git format-patch`:

- `git diff` is only for telling you what you have changed
- `git format-patch` is for creating `.patch`-files that can be applied using `git apply`

Also, on Github there is another, much more comfortable workflow:

1. Fork the repo to your user account
2. Clone it to your local machine
3. Create a feature-branch
4. Change code in that feature branch
5. Push feature branch to your GitHub account
6. Post a pull-request to the upstream repository

See [GitHub's documentation on "Pull Requests"](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests).

Comment: "`git diff` is only for telling you what you have changed". This is not correct, you can apply patches generated with `git diff` by using `git apply`. See [Applying Patches from E-mail](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Distributed-Git-Maintaining-a-Project#Applying-Patches-from-E-mail) in the [Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book). Also, from what I've read, [`git am`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-am.html) seems to be the usual command to use to apply patches generated with [`git format-patch`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-format-patch.html).